# Android - having an animation set

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

I'm trying to make two animations on the same view: one for the backgroundTint and one for the scale... Using `ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder` makes the most sense, as you can just list propertyValueHolder that represent the animations. I have something like this:

```
val enabledColor = context.getColor(R.color.colorAccent)
val disabledColor = context.getColor(R.color.colorDisabled)       

val anim = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(imgBackground,
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 1F, 1.2F),
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 1F, 1.2F),
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("colorFilter", enabledColor, disabledColor)
)
```

However, the `colorFilter` (which is the background tint) is not being animated properly as it's animating an Int... When the animation plays the background_tint is all over the place: yellow, green, etc. I would like to keep this style - using ObjectAnimator to group all the animations.

Previously, I had:

```
    ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(imgBackground, colorAnimProperty, disabledColor, enabledColor)
    val scaleUpAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(imgBackground,
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 1F, 1.2F),
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 1F, 1.2F)
    )
```

Which does the trick, but it's inconvenient as I need an AnimationSet to combine them...

How can I write the background_tint animation using a `PropertyValuesHolder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that we can supply the `PropertyValuesHolder` with an Evaluator function that does the calculation for us. Conveniently, there's an ArgsEvaluator. Hence, it looks like this:

```
animEnable = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(imgBackground,
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 1F, 1.2F),
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 1F, 1.2F),
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofObject("colorFilter", ArgbEvaluator(), disabledColor, enabledColor))
```